# Function to return the date of delivery without Saturdays, Sundays and holidays

Tags: php

How do I write a function in PHP that returns the date of delivery without Saturdays, Sundays and holidays?

For example: for same product delivery is in 3 days for others in 5 days.

If I do a command today I will receive my command in 3 days without Saturdays, Sundays and holidays.

If I do my command now "29/12/2011" for a product "3j" I will receive your command at "4/1/2011"

In the database I have just how much the day for every type product is.

For example:

```
prod1: 3day  
prod2: 5day  
prod3: 7day
```

I tried to do a function but failed.

Comment: Could you be more verbose please? This is quite ambiguous.

Comment: Please pose a better question and try to use full sentences. Return the date of delivery? What delivery? Fetch it from a database? Based on what? So many questions, so little information...

Comment: Have you tried on your own? And how far have you gone? Do some work before asking someoen else to do it for you...

Comment: in databse i have just how mutch the day for evry type prodcte for example prod1 :3day  prod 2 :5day prod 3:7day

Comment: What he is asking is: How to do a dateadd with a number of days, but if the timespan between the actual date and the date with the added days has holidays or weekends included, it shouldn't count them as a day.

Comment: It's a business days calculation. Nothing trivial, but i suggested something below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a really complex subject that you can't really fix with a simple function. You are talking about business days calculation strategies and they involve a lot of thinking.

If you want to process only business days and not business hours, then it get slightly easier.

The first step is to create an array of working days or an array of non working days. For example:

```
//Build the days based of weekends
$nonWorkingDays = array();
foreach($iDate = 0; $iDate < 365; $iDate++){
    $date = strtotime('today +'.$iDate.' day');
    if(date('w', $date) == 0 || date('w', $date) == 6){
        $nonWorkingDays = date('Y-m-d', $date);
    }
}

//Add the holidays
$nonWorkingDays[] = '2011-12-25';
$nonWorkingDays[] = '2012-01-01';

//Determine the date of delivery
$daysToDelivery = 6;
$deliveryDate = time();
while($daysToDelivery > 0){
    $deliveryDate = time() + (24*60*60);
    if(!in_array(date('Y-m-d', $deliveryDate), $nonWorkingDays)){
        $daysToDelivery--;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This code (slightly altered) is used in production for one of my sites:

```
// $dt = date of shipping, $numdays = expected number of days in transit
function realDeliveryDate($dt, $numdays)
{
    $holidays = array("05/30/2011","07/04/2011","09/05/2011","11/24/2011","11/25/2011","12/25/2011","12/31/2011","01/01/2012","05/28/2012","07/04/2012","09/03/2012","11/22/2012","11/23/2012","12/25/2012");
    $checkday = strtotime($dt." +".$numdays." days");
    // check if it's a holiday
    while(in_array(date("m/d/Y",$checkday), $holidays)) {
        $checkday = strtotime(date("m/d/Y",$checkday)." +1 day");
    }
    // make sure it's not Saturday
    if (date("w",$checkday) == 6) {
        $checkday = strtotime(date("m/d/Y",$checkday)." +2 days");
    }
    // make sure it's not Sunday
    if (date("w",$checkday) == 0) {
        $checkday = strtotime(date("m/d/Y",$checkday)." +1 day");
    }
    // make sure it's not another holiday
    while(in_array(date("m/d/Y",$checkday), $holidays)) {
        $checkday = strtotime(date("m/d/Y",$checkday)." +1 day");
    }
    return $checkday;
}
```

Comment: The only way it would fail is if you had an entire week set as a holiday, in which case it would return a Saturday.  For my purposes this will never happen so I just left it this way.

Comment: why not create a function (isHoliday) that takes 1 day and returns true / false.

Comment: @Frank: laziness.  This function is a good example of how a kludge can remain in production.  If I had to, I'd rewrite the function using a single loop.  I just happened to have the file that contains the original function open when I came across this question.  =)

Comment: lol, he sais you are the best, but do I see a green checkmark? A vote up? I say it's appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.localtime.php

This will return you a weekday based on the time you provide.  So if you current time is X and you need to deliver in 2 days you would do `localtime(X + 2*24*3600)`.  The resulting struct will contain the weekday which you can use to move the time forward or backward as you need.

Comment: date delivry = date now + 4 days except Saturday Sunday my brobleme hes how i can do that 4 days except Saturday Sunday

Comment: Replace 2 for 4 the rest is the same.